# QtApplication in Netbeans: "Not connected to D-Bus server"

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I have created simple QtGui Application in QtCreator. it works.
then I have created QtApplication in Netbeans and added files generated in Creator (mainwindow.h,cpp,ui_mainwindow.h) to new Netbeans project.
it compiles, links, builds.
when I try to run executable, the window appears but there is also this message:

> root@comp:~/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_3/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86#
>   ./QtApplication_3 Qt at-spi: error getting the accessibility dbus
>   address:  "Not connected to D-Bus server"  Accessibility DBus not
>   found. Falling back to session bus. Could not connect to DBus. Could
>   not connect to dbus.
>
> (process:10309): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the
>   D-BUS daemon: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the
>   remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security
>   policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network
>   connection was broken.
>
> ** (QtApplication_3:10309): WARNING **: Unable to create Ubuntu Menu Proxy: The connection is closed
>   root@ubuntuamd:~/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_3/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86#

how is this related to network connection? this is just window.
is my approach OK to copy the code generated in Creator? maybe then I have to do something additionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1862995) I have found some tips regarding these errors